# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'. using Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I have recorded a video using mobile camera but now i want to trim that video using a library, after adding the below dependency for trimming feature.

```
implementation 'com.github.a914-gowtham:android-video-trimmer:1.7.0'
```

i am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
```

[image]

Here is my app level build.gradle code:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
compileSdk 32

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.techease.videome"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

//trimmer

implementation 'com.github.a914-gowtham:android-video-trimmer:1.7.0'


}
```

And here is the project level build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub- 
   projects/modules.

  buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   }
  }
 plugins {
  id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
  id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
 }

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Anyone having idea what i am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

In the android studio from "File" menu call "Invalidate caches..."
After loading android studio build the project again. Every thing will be correct.